# Change WebStorm TSLint error lines to warning lines

Tags: angular, typescript, webstorm, tslint

Is there a way to change in WebStorm the error red lines given by TSLint to a less alarming line (Warning or similar)?

Below is an example of what I want to avoid:

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Integration with all linters (be it for JavaScript/TypeScript or PHP etc.) is done as an Inspection (so the results can be shown as errors/warnings and they can be run (results shown) via `Code | Inspect Code`). Therefore:

1. `Settings/Preferences`
2. `Editor | Inspections`
3. Find your linter (use local search box and look for `tslint`)
4. Change `Severity` to a desired level

**P.S.** *In theory*, if linter itself provides a severity (e.g. it says "ERROR" on "WARNING" in actual error description (like TSLint from v5 does)) .. then it may not be possible to override the severity *(it depends on implementation from IDE side -- every linter has own integration implementation)*. Sorry, cannot verify this moment as I'm not using TSLint.

**UPDATE 2018-05-17:**
There were some additional changes made in this regard ([WEB-26119](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-26119)) for next major 2018.2 version -- try it when it will become available (EAP program will start in nearest future).

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: It's available now and the only solution seems to be modifying `defaultSeverity` inside tslint. Too bad, I wish they made it optional.

Comment: Apologies for gravedigging here, but I've just found that as of Webstorm 2019.2.1 (and maybe earlier) there is an option within the TSLint settings above `Use rule severity from configuration file` if this is unticked the severity level chosen in the dropdown can be used.

Answer (score 2):

LazyOne's solution was already what I had in my setup. But then I found this checkbox that solved the problem for me:

[image]

Probably not the best way of doing it if you want to have a better granularization, but it might help some people